# How to check and alter Web API Request Content-Type header?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, content-type

I have a `POST` method in my ASP.NET Web API which would be consumed by a client which can not send `Content-Type` header.
I want to check the `Content-Type` header of Request andif it's null, I would like set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencode`.

How do I achieve this?

P.S. If the request comes without `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencode`, I get:

> The request contains an entity body but no
>   Content-Type header. The inferred media type
>   'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this
>   resource.No MediaTypeFormatter is
>   available to read an object of type 'CustomerModel' from content with
>   media type
>   'application/octet-stream'.System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content,
>   Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far? See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If request doesn't have Content-Type header then it will be set to `application/octet-stream`

[Section 7.2.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html) of the HTTP/1.1 RFC 2616 spec says this about Entity Body Type:

> **When an entity-body is included with a message, the data type of that body is determined via the header fields Content-Type and
>   Content- Encoding**. These define a two-layer, ordered encoding model:
>
> `entity-body := Content-Encoding( Content-Type( data ) )`
>
> Content-Type specifies the media type of the underlying data.
>   Content-Encoding may be used to indicate any additional content
>   codings applied to the data, usually for the purpose of data
>   compression, that are a property of the requested resource. There is
>   no default encoding.
>
> **Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body**. If
>   and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
>   recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
>   content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
>   resource. **If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
>   treat it as type “application/octet-stream”.**

try to clear all formatters first then add only that you need like

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());
```